# Adapting OLS to a parametric regression coefficient

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, consistency

Consider the following linear model
$$
Y_i=X_{i1}\beta_1+\eta_i X_{i2}\beta_2+\epsilon_i
$$

Let $\beta\equiv (\beta_1,\beta_2)$ and $X_i\equiv (X_{i1}, X_{i2})$.

Assume that

**[A1]** We have an i.i.d. sample of observations, $\{Y_i, X_{i}\}_{i=1}^n$.

**[A2]** $E(\epsilon_i| X_{i})=0$.

**[A3]** $E(\eta_i|X_{i})$ is known by the analyst. Let me denote this expected values as $A(X_{i})$. Note that the function $A(\cdot)$ is known.

**[A4]** $\begin{pmatrix}
E(X_{i1}^2) & E(X_{i1} X_{i2} A(X_{i1}, X_{i2}))\\
E(X_{i1}X_{i2}) & E(X_{i2}^2 A(X_{i1}, X_{i2}))\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and its sample analogue are invertible.

My objective is to construct a consistent and asymptotically normal estimator for $\beta$.

This looks similar to the OLS case, with the only exception that $\eta_i$ premultiplies a covariate and is unobserved.

My claim is that, after some minor manipulations, we can still apply the "OLS machinery".

I report here the proof. Is it correct? Is this a well known result and, if yes, could you give me a reference?

---

**Proof**

**Step 1:** Observe that, by **[A2]**, $\beta$ solves the following system of equations
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E(X_{i1}Y_i)\\
E(X_{i2}Y_i)\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
E(X_{i1}^2) & E(X_{i1} X_{i2} \eta_i)\\
E(X_{i1}X_{i2}) & E(X_{i2}^2 \eta_i)\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1\\
\beta_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Step 2:** By **[A3]** combined with the law of iterated expectations,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E(X_{i1}^2) & E(X_{i1} X_{i2} \eta_i)\\
E(X_{i1}X_{i2}) & E(X_{i2}^2 \eta_i)\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
E(X_{i1}^2) & E(X_{i1} X_{i2} A(X_{i1}, X_{i2}))\\
E(X_{i1}X_{i2}) & E(X_{i2}^2 A(X_{i1}, X_{i2}))\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Step 3:** By **[A4]**,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1\\
\beta_2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
E(X_{i1}^2) & E(X_{i1} X_{i2} A(X_{i1}, X_{i2}))\\
E(X_{i1}X_{i2}) & E(X_{i2}^2 A(X_{i1}, X_{i2}))\\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} E(X_{i1}Y_i)\\
E(X_{i2}Y_i)\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Step 4:** Take the sample analogue of Step 3
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat{\beta}_{1,n}\\
\hat{\beta}_{2,n}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{i1}^2 & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i1} X_{i2} A(X_{i1}, X_{i2})\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i1}X_{i2} & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i2}^2 A(X_{i1}, X_{i2})\\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i1}Y_i\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i2}Y_i\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
**Step 5** We can now show that this estimator is consistent and asymptotically normal using classic law of large numbers and central limit theorem as we do for the traditional OLS (under **[A1]** plus existence of some moments). I'm not reporting this part here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the substitution where you divide $\eta_i$ into a deterministic part and a random part

$$\eta_i = \overbrace{f(X_{i1}, X_{i2})}^{E(\eta_i|X_{i})}+ \tilde\epsilon_i$$

Then the equation becomes

$$Y_i=X_{i1}\beta_1+f(X_{i1},X_{i2}) X_{i2}\beta_2+ X_{i2}\beta_2 \tilde\epsilon_i + \epsilon_i$$

and you can combine/simplify/absorb $f(X_{i1},X_{i2}) X_{i2} = X_{i3}$ and $\beta_2 \tilde\epsilon_i = \epsilon_i^\prime$ such that it becomes

$$Y_i=X_{i1}\beta_1+ X_{i3} \beta_2+ X_{i2} \epsilon_i^\prime + \epsilon_i$$

Now, this is like a linear model. You can solve it with OLS. But the variance of the error $X_{i2} \epsilon_i^\prime + \epsilon_i$ is related to $X_{i2}$ and you have [heterogeneous errors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity). You might wish to correct for this, for instance by applying [weighted least squares](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares) to improve the estimate (to decrease the variance of the error in the estimate).

Comment: Thanks. If I follow your methodology, I get $$
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat{\beta}_{1,n}\\
\hat{\beta}_{2,n}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{i1}^2 & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i1} X_{i3})\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i1}X_{i3} & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i3})\\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i1}Y_i\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i3}Y_i\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$ which is different (also numerically) from mine. Could you tell me where I make a mistake in my procedure?

Comment: @TEX You are taking the products with $X_{i1}$ and $X_{i2}$ to create the set of equations for your first step, but you could also take the products $X_{i1}$ and $X_{i2}\eta_i$.

Comment: Thanks. Therefore, can I say that what I propose is an alternative, still correct, approach?

Comment: It seems like you are using some sort of 'method of moments' which results in a linear estimator. But it is not least squares. Yes your estimator might be correct in the sense of being consistent and asymptomatically normal, but it might not have the lowest variance. I believe that this would be a weighted least squares estimator (and since you do not know the exact variance of the points you will have to estimate it and use some form of reweighted least squares).

Comment: May I ask if the substitution $\eta_i=f(X_{i1}, X_{i2})+\tilde{\epsilon}_i$ can be done regardless whether $\eta_i$ is a continuous or discrete random variable?